# Trigger to generate protocol number

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I need help with creating a trigger that will generate a protocol number. The following sequence must be followed:

```
323926YYYYMMDDXXXXXX
```

- 323926 = fixed number
- YYYY   = year
- MM     = month
- DD     = day
- XXXXXX = Number we must automatically generate from 1 that will go to 999999

My difficulty is that this incremental number should return to 000001 after the course of the day, summarizing: Every day the first protocol generated must start with the number 000001

My Code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crm.novo_ticket()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

NEW.protocolo =  '323926' || TO_CHAR(NEW.data_cadastro,'YYYYMMDD') || '000001';

RETURN NEW;

END $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

**Sorted out**

```
SELECT 
    lpad(CAST((SELECT COUNT(1) + 1 INTO quant 
FROM   
    crm.ticket a 
WHERE 
    a.data_cadastro::DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)::DATE;)as VARCHAR),6,'0');
```

Comment: Preface: I do MS SQL not usually postgres. Can you make a table to hold and calculate your key values? Store the date and the incremented number. Now you can compare the date and the number and using a system date function to validate the date you can tell whether to use the next number in sequence or restart the sequence at 000001.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)::DATE` can be simplified to `CURRENT_DATE` Also: the `;` after the cast is wrong

Comment: Using `count(*) + 1` to generate that number is a broken approach if you have more then one concurrent user in your system (plus: it's not going to scale for many rows at all). Using a sequence is the only scalable and concurrency safe way to generate unique numbers. Evan's answer will be a **lot** more efficient as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do this, I would store them all separate and generate them with a function.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  protodate date    DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
  id        serial,
  whatever  text
);
INSERT INTO foo (protodate, whatever)
VALUES
  ('2000-01-01', 'foo'),
  ('2000-01-01', 'bar'),
  ('2000-01-02', 'foo'),
  ('2000-01-03', 'baz');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_protoid( date, int )
RETURNS char(20)
AS $$
  SELECT '323926' || to_char($1, 'YYYYMMDD') || to_char($2, 'FM099999');
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
IMMUTABLE;
```

Now to query it,

```
SELECT to_protoid(
  protodate,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY protodate ORDER BY id)::int
) AS protoid, *
FROM foo;
       protoid        | protodate  | id | whatever 
----------------------+------------+----+----------
 32392620000101000001 | 2000-01-01 |  1 | foo
 32392620000101000002 | 2000-01-01 |  2 | bar
 32392620000102000001 | 2000-01-02 |  3 | foo
 32392620000103000001 | 2000-01-03 |  4 | baz
(4 rows)
```

If that's not good enough you can always create a view or materialized view out of it...

```
CREATE VIEW myfoo
AS
  SELECT to_protoid(
    protodate,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY protodate ORDER BY id)::int
  ) AS protoid, *
  FROM foo;
```

Why would I do this? More efficient storage. You store the inputs to the function rather than output which I find cleaner. You have easy use of indexes on date or int.

Lastly, if you want to, you can have a trigger insert into another table the id and the result of the call to `to_protoid` you *can* do that, though I wouldn't. I wouldn't use the protoid for anything internal. I would use your regular `id` and generate it as demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorted out**

```
SELECT lpad(CAST((SELECT COUNT(1) + 1 INTO quant FROM crm.ticket a WHERE a.data_cadastro::DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)::DATE;)as VARCHAR),6,'0');
```

Comment: I've added your sorted out to your question, please delete this answer, you can edit your question using `Edit` button.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/93735)

Comment: @McNets: if that query solved the problem, then it should definitely be an answer. Not part of the question (and the answer should be accepted).

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)::DATE` can be simplified to `CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: This is not concurrent-safe. Good luck.